# problem with creating store and then passing values ​to mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs

I created a redux store and passed data from the reducer, but it gave an error "Cannot read property 'color' of undefined".

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import store from "./store/store";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";

let rerender=()=> {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
            <Provider store={store}>
            <App/>
            </Provider>
        </React.StrictMode>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
}
rerender();
store.subscribe(()=>{
    rerender()
})
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

store.js:

```
 import React from "react";
 import {combineReducers, createStore} from "redux";
 import {MainReducer} from "./mainReducer";
 const store=createStore(MainReducer);
 export default store;
```

Reducer:

```
let data={
    color:"#bf3636",
    width:20,
    height:20,
    count:2,
    inputs:{}
};
export  const MainReducer=(state=data,action)=>{
//process
}
```

container:

```
import React from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {ChangeColorAC} from "../store/mainReducer";
import {DataFilling} from "./DataFilling";

let MapStateToProps=(state)=>{
    return {
        color:state.MainReducer.color
    }
};
export const DataFillingContainer=connect(MapStateToProps,{ChangeColorAC})(DataFilling)
```

But when you add combineReducers, everything starts working miraculously. What's wrong?

Comment: Can you attach your mainReducer file? I think your reducer named different then 'MainReducer'

Comment: no, my reducer is called that, as it is the only reducer

Comment: i added my answer. I think it helps)

Comment: you misunderstood me a little, with combineReducers my program also works, but without it it doesn't. The docs say what can be done without combineReducers. I'm trying to implement it, but it doesn't work

Comment: To be honest i didn't see something like that in official doc. Could you send me a link so i'll can take a look and help you find out whats wrong)

Comment: https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Comment: i mean this write "let store = createStore (counter)"

Comment: The difference that you're trying to access to store my name of your reducer. But in their example they accessing to value of store. I'll update my answer to show you difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your source code correctly, you made a mistake then created store.

How it should looks like

**reducer**

```
const data={
    color:"#bf3636",
    width:20,
    height:20,
    count:2,
    inputs:{}
};
export  const MainReducer=(state=data,action)=>{
   switch(action.type) {
   ...
   default:
     return state;
  }
}
```

**rootReducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import {MainReducer} from "./mainReducer";


const reducers = {
  mainReducer: MainReducer,
};

export default combineReducers(reducers);
```

**store.js**

```
import React from "react";
 import {combineReducers, createStore} from "redux";
 import rootReducer from "./rootReducer";
 const store=createStore(rootReducer);
 export default store;
```

**container**

```
import React from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {ChangeColorAC} from "../store/mainReducer";
import {DataFilling} from "./DataFilling";

const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
    return {
        color:state.mainReducer.color
    }
};
export const DataFillingContainer=connect(mapStateToProps,{ChangeColorAC})(DataFilling)
```

***Update***
In example from redux

```
function counter(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state - 1
    default:
      return state
  }
}

let store = createStore(counter)
store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()))
```

their store shape looks like `store.getState() === number`

In your code shape of store looks like

```
store.getState() === {
    color:"#bf3636",
    width:20,
    height:20,
    count:2,
    inputs:{}
}
```

And you're expecting to have shape of store

```
store.getState() === {
    MainReducer: {
     color:"#bf3636",
     width:20,
     height:20,
     count:2,
     inputs:{}
    }
}
```

If you want to have named reducers you need to write with combineReducer. If you want to have direct access to values so you need to change your mapStateToProps to

```
const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
    return {
        color:state.color
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I understood the defect)))